# Is there any way to let users declare variables on top of SQL script?

Tags: sql-server

As in the title. I'm writing a long SQL script to perform some QC on imported datasets. Many users will be using the script, and I would like them to declare some variables on top of the script that will be used throughout the rest of the script without there being a need for them to do a mass replace or something:

```
declare @lines_in_imported_file int = 13115;
declare @name_of_user varchar(255)  = 'Pr0no';

-- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE

[...]

select * from imported_data where [username] = @name_of_user;

[...]

if (@lines_in_imported_file <> 0)
    select * from imported_data
;
```

This would only work if the variable is declared and used in the same statement. However, is there any way of getting this done (except for dynamic SQL)?

`[--edit--]`

```
create table [CA131RB01_VARS] (
    name varchar(10)
  , value varchar(10)
);

insert into [CA131RB01_VARS] (name, value) values ('lines_in_imported_file', '13115');
insert into [CA131RB01_VARS] (name, value) values ('name_of_user', 'pr0no');
```

Comment: You could put the variables into a table. You can reference that table wherever you wish, and destroy the table at the end of the script.

Comment: I have been thinking about that, but it would require the users to update a few insert statements -- possibly breaking the queries. I would have thought declaring some variables was less error-prone :)

Comment: What do you mean "it would require the users to update a few insert statements"? You can create the table yourself and insert the variables the user fills in, right? Perhaps I don't understand your goal enough...

Comment: Please see the `[--edit--]`...the user now has to fiddle in the 2 `insert`-statements to get the correct values into the database. What if he makes a mistake (e.g. removing a quote). I'd rather not have users fiddling with the queries themselves.

Comment: Well, why not do the insert like `insert into [CA131RB01_VARS] (name, value) values ('lines_in_imported_file', @lines_in_imported_file);`. That way you still have to declare variables on top of the script, but reference the created table with  the variable values further on.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [Scripting variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188714.aspx), essentially replacement variables that take their value from sqlcmd parameters, environment variables or `:setvar` statements inside the script itself. That's what SSDT uses when creating change/publish scripts to pass server and database names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something along these lines:

```
declare @lines_in_imported_file int = 13115;
declare @name_of_user varchar(255)  = 'Pr0no';

-- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE

create table [CA131RB01_VARS] (
    name varchar(10)
  , value varchar(10)
);

insert into [CA131RB01_VARS] (name, value) values ('lines_in_imported_file', @lines_in_imported_file);
insert into [CA131RB01_VARS] (name, value) values ('name_of_user', @name_of_user);

[...]

select       * 
from         imported_data id
inner join   [CA131RB01_VARS] vars
      on     vars.value = id.[username]
where        vars.name = 'name_of_user'

[...]

if ((select value from CA131RB01_VARS where name = 'lines_in_imported_file') <> 0)
    select * from imported_data
;

drop table [CA131RB01_VARS];
```